# NavigationBarItem: BackButtonItem in Google Maps Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, google-places

I just completed an map app that uses the Google Maps, Google Places, and Google Place Picker API frameworks. Quick question, though. How do a create a back button within my Google Maps Navigation Bar so that I can dismiss to the previous View Controller that performed the segue to the Google Map View Controller in the first place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigation back button comes pre-loaded with the navigation controller. In the storyboard, you have to drag out a navigation controller, set it to root view controller (attach the horizontal arrow to it), and it will automatically load the back button.